# Visual Studio IDE error - Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I'm getting the following error when trying to open any .cs file in my solution.

[image]

I've tried 1) restarting Visual Studio, 2) restarting computer, 3) delete all obj folders, 4) delete all .vs files and folders and still I can't open any files.

Same error message if I double click on the file in solution explorer or use F7.

The files do exist.

I've also tried disabling resharper in case it was that causing the issues, but it doesn't help.

I've also tried navigating to classes using Ctrl+T, entering class name and selecting the class. No error messages, but nothing loads.

Comment: does it happen in a new solution?

Comment: @Ken Tucker, no it doesn't happen on a new solution. Only a couple of existing solutions.

Comment: I've found the problem. My solution was stored in my OneDrive folder which was doing automatic syncing. Moving the solutions out of OneDrive made the errors go away!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here was that my solution folder was inside my OneDrive folder, which was doing automatic syncing with my OneDrive account.

Moving the solution folders out of the one drive folder made the errors go away.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for those who want to keep the project in our onedrive folder for backup purposes?

Comment: My solution is not being synced with OneDrive, so this answer didn't resolve my error. Also, I was also receiving an "Object not set to an instance" error upon starting IE Express.  The web browser I was using for IIS Express (for running the Web Api) was Chrome. I switched it use IE and voila, it worked. Not sure why Chrome was causing the error though. When I corrected the null ref error, so went the disposed object error.

Comment: for anyone coming here in 2021 use Git for backing up any VS projects, it integrates brilliantly.

Answer (score 42):

This is the error I got when I tried to open an old solution: `Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'WorkspaceContext'`. I found the solution from [Refat Eid's blog](https://refateid.blogspot.com/2018/10/visual-studio-cannot-access-disposed.html).

> You just need to open the following directory and delete the content there:
> `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache`

Depending on your Visual Studio, you may have a different version number in your `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation`. If you are not sure, copy the content to a temp folder first.

Other answers, either upgrading or reinstalling, basically serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 9):

I have the same issue but in **Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition** latest update which is **Version 16.7.2**.

After the update, all of my solutions that was bound in [Azure Devops](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/?nav=min) were experiencing problems when I try to checkin with the same error message as OP.

So, I deleted the folder but instead of:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache
```

I deleted this instead:

```
%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\8.0\Cache
```

Then re-open my solution and it will rebind automatically after this message box:

[image]

In case it didn't rebind. Try to re-open your solution via `Team Explorer` -> `Source Control Explorer` and double click the solution directly on the `Source Control Explorer`.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it was solved by simply restarting the visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem, by re-downloading the vs installer (i apparently deleted my old copy), and telling it to run an update as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is insane.  Why should OneDrive synchronization cause this problem?

My Windows 10 system just installed a bunch of new updates today (4/11/2018).  Immediately after those updates were installed I was unable to open *any* of my C# files in VS 2017 (error: Cannot access disposed object).  All of these files opened without problem prior to today's updates.

Moving the projects off OneDrive solved the problem, as did opening the files in a previous version of VS (I tried VS 2015).

All of my VS projects are stored on OneDrive, with copies on my local drive.  OneDrive claims that all my files are up to date, so I don't understand how this can be related to OneDrive synchronization.

Has anyone else suddenly run into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have the solution file and its folder under OneDrive sync folder. Right click OneDrive system tray and click Settings. Under the Settings tab, uncheck Save space and download files as you use them checkbox (Files On-Demand)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, however after I upgraded to the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 (15.6.7), the error message disappeared, so I could open all files in the solution again. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was due to deleting solution configurations which were not immediately saved, just saving all and restarting Visual Studio solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my VS2019.  Closed VS.  **Disable Sync of One Drive Files, and reload project.**  Problem gone!  It definitely seems somewhat related to OneDrive.  Even though in my case all files were Sync'ed still pausing it and re-opening VS resolved.  It could have been just restart of VS...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. My solution is not stored in onedrive, but locally.
the full error message was :

error performing rename. cannot access a disposed object. object name invisibleEditor

the error happened when I renamed first the file from the solution-explorer window then clikced yes, which normally changes the class name as well, however this did not happen.

then when i tried to change the class name the error was thrown.

I restarted VS 2019 Enterprise 16.11.3 few times but that did not help.

I resolved this by:

1. undoing the renaming of the file in the solution explorer
2. deleting the .vs folder in my solution directory
3. deleting all the bin and obj folders in on my projects within then solution.

the renaming was then successful.

the error stack was :

System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'InvisibleEditor'.
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.InvisibleEditor.get_TextBuffer()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.VisualStudioWorkspaceImpl.ApplyTextDocumentChange(DocumentId documentId,SourceText newText)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.VisualStudioWorkspaceImpl.ApplyDocumentTextChanged(DocumentId documentId,SourceText newText)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace.ApplyChangedDocument(ProjectChanges projectChanges,DocumentId documentId)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace.ApplyProjectChanges(ProjectChanges projectChanges)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace.TryApplyChanges(Solution newSolution,IProgressTracker progressTracker)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.VisualStudioWorkspaceImpl.TryApplyChanges(Solution newSolution,IProgressTracker progressTracker)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace.TryApplyChanges(Solution newSolution)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.InlineRename.InlineRenameSession.ApplyRename(Solution newSolution,IWaitContext waitContext)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.InlineRename.InlineRenameSession.CommitCore(IWaitContext waitContext,Boolean previewChanges)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.InlineRename.InlineRenameSession.<>c__DisplayClass78_0.b__0(IWaitContext waitContext)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.Utilities.VisualStudioWaitIndicator.Wait(String title,String message,Boolean allowCancel,Boolean showProgress,Action`1 action)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.InlineRename.InlineRenameSession.CommitWorker(Boolean previewChanges)
at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.InlineRename.Dashboard.Commit()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)